# finding p-value from goodness of fit test in fitdistrplus package in r

Tags: r, distribution, goodness-of-fit

I want to fit a distribution to my data. I use fitdistrplus package in r to find the distribution. I can compare the goodness of fit results for different distributions to see which one is more fitted to my data but I don't know how to check the pvalue for goodness of fit test for each of the distributions. The results might show that among gamma, lognormal and exponential, exponential distribution has the lower statistics for anderson darling test but I don't know how to check if pvalue for these tests does not reject the null hypothesis. Is there any built in function in R which gives the pvalues? 
Here is a piece of code I used as an example:

```
    d <- sample(100,50)
    library(fitdistrplus)
    descdist(d)
    fitg <- fitdist(d,"gamma")
    fitg2 <- fitdist(d,"exp")
    gofstat(list(fitg,fitg2))
```

This code makes 50 random numbers from 0 to 100 and tries to find best fitted model to these data. If descdist(d) shows that gamma and exponential are the two candidates as the best fitted model, fitg and fitg2 finds their related models. the last line compares Ks and anderson darling statistics to show which distribution is most fitted. Distribution with lower value for these tests is the best. However, I dont know how to find p-values for fitg and fitg2 before comparying them. If pvalues show that none of these distributions are not fitted to these data, there is no point to comparing their goodness of fit statistics to my knowledge.

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example with code?  This will make it easier for others to help you.

Comment: @JasonAizkalns I edited the question as suggested. Thanks

Comment: I don't really think that an example does help. There are an infinite number of possible distributions and saying that there is a probability that one particular one is or is not the "correct distribution" doesn't really seem sensible. I think you need to do more research on the theory behind your goodness of fit process. It's not really labeled as a "test", but rather some sort of distance measure.

Comment: Close vote intended to gather support for migration to CrossValidated.com